# How to parse a string into a date time format in C#

Tags: c#

i have a string which contains date time this...

```
string S="08/18/2013 24:00:00"
DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(S, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

i want to parse it into date time but shows an exception like this.
The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar                              System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

please tell me any solution for this problem.

Comment: Just a thought there is no time 24:00:00. Dont know if that is your problem though.

Comment: @ckv: There is in ISO-8601. It's "the end of the day" basically.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for that interesting fact.

Comment: @user1882191 Consider to accept one of this answers..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with the hour being 24. `DateTime` doesn't support this, as far as I'm aware.

Options:

- Use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project which [*does* support 24:00:00](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/userguide/localdatetime-patterns.html), but basically handles it by adding a day (it doesn't preserve a difference between that and "end of previous day")
- Keep using `DateTime`, manually replace "24:00:00" with "00:00:00" when it occurs, and remember to add a day afterwards

If you want to preserve the information that it was actually "end of the day" you'd need to do that separately, and keep the information alongside the `DateTime` / `LocalDateTime`.

You should *also* parse with the invariant culture as other answers have suggested - you're not trying to parse a culture-specific string; you know the exact separators etc.

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't notice 24 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string S="08/18/2013 00:00:00";  // here is the first problem occurred
DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(S, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`The "HH" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

> The "HH" custom format specifier (plus any number of additional "H"
>   specifiers) represents the hour as a number from **00** through **23**; that
>   is, the hour is represented by a zero-based 24-hour clock that counts
>   the hours since midnight.

So, using `24` as an hour is invalid on this case.

Try with `hh` format with `00` instead like;

```
string S = "08/18/2013 00:00:00";
DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(S, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/c6248q).

If you really want to use 24:00:00 as a hour, take a look [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) which developed by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).